# How to define a PDF in HSPICE with or without Verilog-A?

Tags: verilog, circuit, cadence, pspice

I have a pdf function which is an exponential function divided by a definite integral. I have two problems:

1) How do I define my own PDF in HSPICE? ( I have found HSPICE has Gaussian distribution, but that's not what I am looking for)

2) How do I solve a definite integral in HSPICE?

Can I solve these two problems with a model in Verilog-A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might get a better response for this question over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this modeled in SPICE using a generalized nonlinear current source and a 1-H inductor to perform the integration (C=L dI/dt).  Example:

```
G1 1 2 VALUE = {100uA*sin(V(3,2))}
L1 1 3 1H
R1 1 3 1ohm
```